# How do I create a Processing library that adds a new function to the language?

Tags: function, processing, addition

I want to create a Processing library that adds a single function to Processing. A single command. How do I do this?

So I want to be able to write on Processing this:

```java
void setup() {
    drawMyCustomShape()
}
```

In a way that `drawMyCustomShape` will be on my custom library implementation.

Thanks!

Note: this question is not about creating a new library in processing. Is about creating a library that exports one new command (so you can using without caring of the container class instance).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, are you sure you really need to create an entire library? You could just add that class to your sketch without needing to deploy it as a library. If you're worried about clutter, just put it in its own tab.

If you really need to create a library, then there are three tutorials that you need to read:

- [Library Overview](https://github.com/processing/processing4/wiki/Library-Overview)
- [Library Basics](https://github.com/processing/processing4/wiki/Library-Basics)
- [Library Guidelines](https://github.com/processing/processing4/wiki/Library-Guidelines)

But basically, you need to create a Java project (in an IDE like eclipse, or with a basic text editor and the command line) that uses Processing as a library. That's where you'd put your `MyLibrary` class. You'd then export it as a `.jar` file, and then import that `.jar` file into Processing. You would then be able to use your class exactly like you can use any other Processing library.

Your proposed setup has some other issues (how are you going to access the `sketch` variable from the `static` function?), but I'd suggest treating them as separate questions after you get the basics in place.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I understand the basic concepts around creating a new library. I need it as a library because I will use it in a college class and I need to hide implementation from students. My **specific need** is to have a library that adds a command to Processing, as shown in the example above. I don't know how this is done. Maybe it's not about making a static function. I will edit the question to remove my idea of static method that seems to make it confusing.

Comment: @AryPabloBatista Well, I think my answer is still the answer. If you want to create a library, then you're going to have to follow the steps I outlined. You aren't going to be able to simply add a function to Processing, unless you build Processing itself from its source and add your function that way. Processing is open source so this is doable, but note that none of the above will 100% prevent mischievous students from decompiling the source and getting at the implementation anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So, finally I found the most adequate answer for my case.

**The solution for this is to implement a new Processing Mode** that extends the builtin Java Mode. To include static members to the main processing program you will need to add a new static import to the ones that processing adds to your code.

You can do this by forking the Mode Template for 3.0 that @joelmoniz created from @martinleopold:
https://github.com/joelmoniz/TemplateMode/tree/3.0-compatibility

There is a good tutorial here: 
http://pvcresin.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/03/17/210135

**Why is the most adequate solution? :** I think this is the best way to achieve new static methods in processing code and ensure an easy distribution! You just have to set the mode folder in your `sketchbook/modes` folder. If I were to fork processing it would be a big deal to prepare distributions for all operative systems and also to keep update with main project.

**My particular solution**:

To add my static imports into Processing I implemented a custom mode where I overrode the `PdePreprocessor` class which wraps the processing code with all the Java procesing code. So, the idea was to add more imports to the imports that the `PdePreprocessor` generates on the generated Java source.

In my custom `PdePreprocessor` I overrode the `getCoreImports` method to add my custom methods. I did this here because I consider the new imports are part of the core of my custom mode. You could also achieve this by overriding `writeImports` method.

In order to use my `PdePreprocessor` implementation I had to overrode the following classes:

- `Commander`
- `JavaBuild`
- `JavaEditor`
- `JavaMode`
- `JavaEditor`

I had to implement a new `JavaBuild` which preprocesses the `Sketch` with my custom `PdePreprocessor`. And also use my custom `JavaBuild` in all the places where the Processing Java Mode instances the build class. Please share with us if there is a better way to do what I did.

Here is the github for my solution: http://github.com/arypbatista/processing-inpr/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are actually looking to create your own extension of the Processing library, as in actually change the core jar file.

You can extend the actual Processing library by forking off of its main branch on Github. By writing your function `drawMyCustomShape` into the actual core in the forked version, you can then build the Processing Development Environment from your copy of the code. Using that particular copy of the PDE, you could do what you're describing.

Once you compile this build, you could actually distribute this copy of the PDE to your college students. They would be able to use your function as if nothing were changed. (I'm guessing that this is for an intro-level class at the college level, so that's why you would have to hide implementation from your students?)

Here's some links to get you started:

- [Processing github](https://github.com/processing/processing)
- [Instructions for building the PDE from source](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Build-Instructions)